# Query is returning empty records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select 3 columns from a table which needs to satisfy the following requirements (in the **UPDATE** section)

```
        SELECT A.ACTIVITY_CD, A.REASON_CD, A.REASON_DESC
    INTO #TmpViewResult
    FROM CFG_REASON A, #TmpViewParam B
    WHERE A.ACTIVITY_CD = CASE WHEN B.ActivityCd = '' THEN A.ACTIVITY_CD ELSE B.ActivityCd END
    AND A.REASON_CD = CASE WHEN B.ReasonCd = '' THEN A.REASON_CD ELSE B.ReasonCd END
```

It is returning empty records for me. What did i do wrong here and how should i change it?

**UPDATE:**

The answer below does not work for me. It is still giving me empty records. I have this code before the queries above.

```
SELECT ActivityCd, ReasonCd
    INTO #TmpViewParam
    FROM OPENJSON(@Param)
    WITH (ActivityCd NVARCHAR(10),
    ReasonCd NVARCHAR(10))
```

Below is the Param passed, both param can be empty or contains value.

```
@Param = N'{"ACTIVITY_CD": "RS00001", "REASON_CD": ""}'
```

[Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5jqF.png)

ActivityCd

- Blank = all activity
- With value = Specific activity code

ReasonCd

- Blank = all reason for the above selected activitycd
- With value = specific reason for the selected activity code.

Expected result with the @Param above :
{"ACTIVITY_CD": "RS00001", "REASON_CD": "xxx", "REASON_DESC": "xxx"}
and the rest of the records according to the param

Comment: It's a `CASE` **expression**, and ideally, don't; it'll make your query non-SARGable. Stick to proper boolean logic with `AND` and `OR` clauses.

Comment: On a seperate note, it's 2021! You've had *29 years* to adopt the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax; why are still using that ANSI-89 implicit join syntax? Also, learn to alias your objects properly. There isn't a single `B` in `#TmpViewParam` so why give it that alias? [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: I am quite new to the industry so i am trying to improve. :)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question (or using a db/sql fiddle).

Comment: already did as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want:

```
SELECT r.ACTIVITY_CD, r.REASON_CD, r.REASON_DESC
INTO #TmpViewResult
FROM CFG_REASON r CROSS JOIN
     #TmpViewParam p
WHERE (r.ACTIVITY_CD = p.ActivityCd OR p.ActivityCd = '') AND
      (r.REASON_CD = p.ActivityCd OR p.REASON_CD = '') ;
```

This uses the parameter table as a filter on each column, if the value is there.  Note:  `NULL` is commonly used to mean "don't use the parameter" rather than `''`.

Comment: A `CROSS JOIN` followed by `WHERE` is nearly as bad as a `,`

Comment: @WilsonLoo . . . "not working" is not helpful.  Please explain what you mean.  This should be filtering the rows based on the parameter values in the table.

Comment: i have updated the post by saying it is still returning empty records for me as well as adding more codes before it if it helps in solving the problem